# Node.js prefers IPv4 over IPv6

Tags: node.js, docker, dns

I'm using DNS64 on a system that doesn't have an IPv4 address. Unfortunately the DNS54 server does not remove the A record. Normally this isn't a problem because most of the tools, like `curl`, prefer IPv6 over IPv4.

I'm running a Node.js application (Node-RED) with Node.js 18 in a Docker container on the system. For some reason the Node.js HTTP client always tries to connect to an IPv4 address, even when an AAAA record is present.

How can I make it use the IPv6 address instead?

I have tried setting `--dns-result-order=verbatim` but it didn't help. I noticed that when I connect to  `localhost` it actually uses `::1`, but for all other "real" domain names it tries to use IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a solution, but I have found a **workaround**.

If I remove the automatically assigned IPv4 address from the Docker container, Node.js starts resolving hostnames to IPv6 addresses and connecting to them.

I'm doing this by running this immediately after `docker run`:

```
docker exec -it -u root --privileged <container> ip -4 addr flush dev eth0
```